# Why store python variables in a class outside init, and is self required?

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3

Consider the following two code samples.

Two questions:

1: What is the difference between the two approaches? For what benefit would I implement A versus B?

2: In sample A, is the self variable prefix required?

Sample A:

```
class DoSomething():

    self.dispatcher = {
    'SaveToS3': self.savetos3,
    'SendWebHook': self.webhook,
    'AddToQueue': self.addtoqueue,
    'SendSms': self.sendsms,
    'SendEmail': self.sendemail,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Sample B:

```
class DoSomething():

    def __init__(self):
        self.dispatcher = {
        'SaveToS3': self.savetos3,
        'SendWebHook': self.webhook,
        'AddToQueue': self.addtoqueue,
        'SendSms': self.sendsms,
        'SendEmail': self.sendemail,
        }
```

Comment: Sample A will not work: `self` doesn't exist. You could ditch the `self.` prefix, but now you have a *class* initialization, as opposed to an *instance* initialization (as in Sample B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Sample A, `dispatcher` is shared among all instances of the class, and so modifying it will modify `self.dispatcher` for every `DoSomething`.  With Sample B, on the other hand, each instance gets a separate `self.dispatcher`, and modifying one will leave all of the others alone.  Sample A also lets you access `DoSomething.dispatcher` without involving any instances, while this won't work in B.
2. `self.` is actually not allowed at "class level," as there is no "`self`" object defined there.

Comment: It is not that `self` is not allowed; it is just not defined as you mentioned. And it would be misleading to use it if it were defined due to Python convention for the name of the first argument in the methods.

Comment: OK makes sense.  So consider the case in which I change 'self.dispatcher' in sample A to 'dispatcher'. Are the 'self.' function identifiers in the dispatcher valid or should they also not be prefixed with 'self'?

Comment: @DukeDougal: `self.` would still be required there, though `DoSomething.dispatcher` would work as well.  (It would not work in Sample B.)

Answer (score 0):

To add. The `self` is the name by convention. Theoretically, you can use whatever identifier for the purpose, but it is not recommended.

Technically, when you "call" a class, you get the reference to the just created instance of the class (i.e. to the object of the class). It has exactly the same value as had the `self` inside the `__init__(self, arguments)` or in any other method of the class.

Classes should be given *noun* identifiers, not the *verbs* as it does not make sense from the logical point of view. If you create the object:

```
obj = Something()
```

and when you call the `method` of the object like this

```
obj.method(arguments)
```

then it is exactly the same like

```
Something.method(obj, arguments)
```

The later explains why the `self` is used in definitions. It is more explicit than in other languages (say C++). As the `obj` knows internally its class, you can look at the `obj.method(arguments)` as if it were only a syntactic sugar. (But it is very well known and expected syntactic sugar.) Actually, this is the way how objects are implemented probably in all programming languages. The usual difference only is that the `self`-like argument is assumed as implicit when writing definitions of methods.